# Resize event.Adding and removing classes

Tags: javascript, html

What I am doing wrong? When document width is > than 952 and < 1152 I want to add "d-none" to element with id "r5" and at the same time remove font-awesome icon class' "d-none".If width is > than 1152 then..I am removing class "d-none" which have element with id "r5" and I add class "d-none" to fontawesomeicome..I check document width.

html

```
    <div class="navigation-menu w-32 flex-row">
        <ul>
            <a href="#"><li class="visible">Раздел1</li></a>
            <a href="#"><li class="visible">Раздел2</li></a>
            <a href="#"><li class="visible">Раздел3</li></a>
            <a href="#"><li class="visible">Раздел4</li></a>
            <a href="#"><li class="visible" id="r5">Раздел5</li></a>
            <a href="#"><li class="d-none" id="fade-i"><i class="fas fa-chevron-circle-down"></i></li></a>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

JS

```
    var documentWidth = $(document).width();


$(window).resize(function() {
   if( documentWidth > 952 && documentWidth < 1152){
       document.getElementById("r5").classList.add("d-none");
       document.getElementById("fade-i").classList.remove("d-none");
   } else{
       if(documentWidth > 1153){
        document.getElementById("fade-i").classList.add("d-none");
        document.getElementById("r5").classList.remove("d-none");  
       }    
   }
});
```

[image]

Comment: What is the issue here?

Comment: You may want to take a look at this : https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

Comment: it works good when I am narrow a document window,but then I expand a document window  if(documentWidth > 1153){
        document.getElementById("fade-i").classList.add("d-none");
        document.getElementById("r5").classList.remove("d-none");  
       }   this part doesn't work

Comment: yeah,mediaquery is easy..I am trying to do this with JS